# Add data from a data table to another using values of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, apply

I know the question is confusing, but I hope the example will make it simple.

I have two tables:

```
x    y
1    23
2    34
3    76
4    31
```

&

```
x    y
1    78
3    51
5    54
```

I need to add the y columns based on x values. I can do it using loops, but don't want to. It will be better if the solution uses `base`, `dplyr`, `data.table` functions as I am most familiar with those, I am okay with `apply` family of functions as well. The output should look like this:

```
x    y
1    101
2    34
3    127
4    31
5    54
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to combine the two dataset, group by `x` and summarize `y` with `sum` and there are a couple of ways to do it:

`data.table`:

```
rbind(dtt1, dtt2)[, .(y = sum(y)), by = x]

#    x   y
# 1: 1 101
# 2: 2  34
# 3: 3 127
# 4: 4  31
# 5: 5  54
```

base R `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(y ~ x, rbind(dtt1, dtt2), FUN = sum)
```

`dplyr`:

```
rbind(dtt1, dtt2) %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(y = sum(y))
```

---

The data:

```
library(data.table)

dtt1 <- fread('x    y
1    23
2    34
3    76
4    31')

dtt2 <- fread('x    y
1    78
3    51
5    54')
```

Comment: Had to group by 2 columns, so, it did not work. But I circumvented it by using a slight variation of your method. So, it helped, really. thank you.